# Suavizar trazado de líneas e intervalos de confianza utilizando ggplot

Tags: r

Utilizando el siguiente código dibujo una serie de líneas y de intervalos de confidencia del 95% usando `geom_line` y `geom_ribbon`.

Me gustaría suavizar el trazado de la línea de medias y de los sombreados de los intervalos de confidencia. He intentado utilizar `geom_smooth`, pero no consigo el ajuste deseado.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
tribble(    ~y,   ~z,    ~g,
            1     ,"A",   1,
            2     ,"A",   1,
            2     ,"B",   1,
            3     ,"B",   1,
            1.5   ,"C",   1,
            2     ,"C",   1,
            2     ,"D",   1,
            2     ,"D",   1,
            3     ,"A",   2,
            3.5   ,"A",   2,
            0.5   ,"B",   2,
            2     ,"B",   2,
            2     ,"C",   2,
            2     ,"C",   2,
            1.5   ,"D",   2,
            1     ,"D",   2,
            4     ,"A",   3,
            3.5   ,"A",   3,
            5.5   ,"B",   3,
            3     ,"B",   3,
            3.3   ,"C",   3,
            2.1   ,"C",   3,
            1.3   ,"D",   3,
            1.2   ,"D",   3)-> data


z = factor(z, levels = c("A", "B", "C", "D"))
data %>%
  group_by(g, z) %>%
  summarise(media = mean(y), 
            desvio = sd(y),    
            error_est = desvio / sqrt(n()),   
            intervalo_sup = media + (2*error_est),   
            intervalo_inf = media - (2*error_est)) %>%  
  ggplot(aes(x = g, y = media, color = z)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = z, color = z), size=0.5) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(x = as.numeric(g), ymax = intervalo_sup,                
                  ymin = intervalo_inf, 
                  fill = z),
              alpha=0.3, colour = NA) +
  labs(x = "X", y = "Y", fill = "Condition", color = "Condition") +
  scale_fill_manual(labels = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), values = c("blue","green","red", "black")) +
  scale_color_manual(labels = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), values = c("blue","green","red", "black")) +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = seq(1, 3, by = 1)) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.text=element_text(size=12)) +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=14),
        axis.title=element_text(size=14))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: como lo mencionas, `geom_smooth()` es un método que te puede ayudar, revisa esto: - [https://eliocamp.github.io/codigo-r/2018/06/tu-propio-geom-smooth/](https://eliocamp.github.io/codigo-r/2018/06/tu-propio-geom-smooth/) - [https://plot.ly/ggplot2/smooth/](https://plot.ly/ggplot2/smooth/) - [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hxk2cgdChUw](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hxk2cgdChUw)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lamentablemente los gráficos de R en **Windows**, en el panel de gráficos, se ven no del todo bien. En el caso de las líneas es sumamente notable, que éstas se ven con un estilo "serrucho" ("jagged"). Haciendo un "zoom" a tú gráfica se hace bien notable este efecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es normal que ocurra esto, cualquier línea que no sea perfectamente horizontal o vertical, en cualquier monitor sufrirá este efecto. Lo que ocurre es que en algunos casos se contempla esta situación y se implementan técnicas de aliasado ("aliasing"), que básicamente agregan "pixeles" de colores más suaves, lo que hace que percibamos mucho mejor las líneas. **Windows** implementa el alisado de fuentes, pero no el de otro tipo de gráfico, **lamentablemente a la fecha, no hay una solución**, aunque hay [una mejora agendada](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/2142) al respecto en **Rstudio**.

Tanto Linux, como MAC, tiene mejores implementaciones para mostrar gráficos, por lo que este problema se minimiza mucho en estos sistemas operativos. Particularmente en Linux (en Mac creo que también), se usa por defecto [Cairo](https://cairographics.org/), que resuelve mucho mejor este problema.

Una solución paliativa, es aprovechar que se puede configurar a "Cairo" como dispositivo por defecto para salvar un gráfico `ggplot`, por lo que salvar la gráfica en un `png`, por ejemplo, este no tendrá los problemas que notamos en el panel de los gráficos de Rstudio. Estamos hablando de la rutina [`ggsave()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/versions/3.2.0/topics/ggsave) que puedes implementar al final de tu lote, con lo cual, verás el gráfico como siempre en el panel, pero adicionalmente salvarás un imagen correctamente alisada:

```
data %>%
  group_by(g, z) %>%
  summarise(media = mean(y), 
            desvio = sd(y),    
            error_est = desvio / sqrt(n()),   
            intervalo_sup = media + (2*error_est),   
            intervalo_inf = media - (2*error_est)) %>%  
  ggplot(aes(x = g, y = media, color = z)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = z, color = z), size=0.5) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(x = as.numeric(g), ymax = intervalo_sup,                
                  ymin = intervalo_inf, 
                  fill = z),
              alpha=0.3, colour = NA) +
  labs(x = "X", y = "Y", fill = "Condition", color = "Condition") +
  scale_fill_manual(labels = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), values = c("blue","green","red", "black")) +
  scale_color_manual(labels = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), values = c("blue","green","red", "black")) +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = seq(1, 3, by = 1)) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.text=element_text(size=12)) +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=14),
        axis.title=element_text(size=14)) +
  # Salvamos en png
  ggsave(file="ejemplo.png", height = 5, width = 7, dpi = 320,  type = "cairo")
```

Ejemplo final (adjuntamos ejemplo.png):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y si hacemos un "zoom"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Vemos una notable mejora en la líneas, y una mejora menor en las sombras o areas.

### Adenda al 8/6/2021

Según parece a partir de [esta versión](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/release-notes/rstudio-1-4-wax-begonia/) se llega a leer en el `Changlog`:

> The default renderer used for the RStudio graphics device can now be
> customized. (#2142)

Por lo que entiendo, que se podría probar alguno de los posibles `["default", "cairo", "cairo-png", "quartz", "windows", "ragg"]`, por ejemplo `cairo`

Y efectivamente, se puede configurar `cairo` com render

```
options(RStudioGD.backend = "cairo")
```

Y mejora bastante la calidad de la líneas rectas.