# Suavizado (Alisado o simplificado) de polígonos en mapa con ggplot2 y sf

Tags: r, ggplot2

¿Cómo se pueden suavizar los polígonos de un mapa producido con ggplot y sf?

He utilizado el package sf para extraer los polígonos de un archivo shapefile

```
geomunicipios <- st_read("ruta/archivo.shp")
Reading layer `archivo' from data source 
  `ruta\archivo.shp' 
  using driver `ESRI Shapefile'
Simple feature collection with 45 features and 10 fields
Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -2.344411 ymin: 37.37375 xmax: -0.647983 ymax: 38.75509
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
```

Y ggplot2 para trazar el mapa:

```
rmurcia <- ggplot(data = geomunicipios) + 
 geom_sf(aes(fill=columna),color="#FFFFFF",size=1)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**RESUELTO**

Resuelto con package `smoothr` y aplicando la función `smooth` al dataframe sf que contiene las geometrías de los polígonos y a continuación trazamos el mapa:

```
geosmunicipios <- smooth(geomunicipios, method = "ksmooth", smoothness = 12)

rmurcia <- ggplot(data = geosmunicipios) + 
 geom_sf(aes(fill=columna),color="#FFFFFF",size=1)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Que entiendes por "suavizado" de polígonos? ¿no tendrá que ver con esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/285200/suavizar-trazado-de-l%c3%adneas-e-intervalos-de-confianza-utilizando-ggplot?

Comment: He añadido el gráfico generado con plotly ```ggplotly(rmurcia)``` que aunque mejora el resultado que se puede ver en el panel de R, no es el deseado.

Comment: No es un problema de zoom y de efecto serrucho. En este caso se podría hablar de suavizado como alisado, simplificando las líneas.  No sé si me consigo explicar.

Comment: Por eso preguntaba, no sé bien entonces a que te refieres con el término "suavizar".

Comment: "suavizar" = líneas menos quebradas, a ver si así consigo explicarme

Comment: ¿Cómo podría utilizar package rmapshaper o package smoothr?

Comment: Resuelto con package ```smoothr``` y aplicando la función ```smooth``` al dataframe sf que contiene las geometrías de los polígonos ```geosmunicipios <- smooth(geomunicipios, method = "ksmooth", smoothness = 12)```

Answer (score 1):

Para realizar el suavizado de los polígonos he analizado tres alternativas:

- i. package "smoothr":
  `geosmunicipios <- smooth(geomunicipios, method = "ksmooth", smoothness = 12)`
- ii. package "rmapshaper": `geosmunicipios <- ms_simplify(geomunicipios, keep = 0.02500, weighting = 12)`
- iii. package "sf": `geosmunicipios <- st_simplify(geomunicipios, dTolerance = 50, preserveTopology = TRUE)`

Hay que probar diferentes valores para los parámetros de las diferentes alternativas para ajustar a nuestras necesidades y obtener el resultado deseado.

Para reproducir este caso, la descarga se puede hacer desde: centrodedescargas.cnig.es/CentroDescargas/index.jsp

Hay que seguir esta línea de enlaces:
Información geográfica de referencia - Límites municipales, provinciales y autonómicos - Descargar: lineas_limite.zip.

Una vez descomprimido el archivo .zip encontramos el archivo shapefile:
SIGLIM_Publico_INSPIRE - SHP_ETRS89 - recintos_municipales_inspire_peninbal_etrs89 - recintos_municipales_inspire_peninbal_etrs89.shp

Finalmente, para este caso he optado por utilizar rmapshaper, produce un resultado satisfactorio con un tamaño reducido de archivo .pdf, donde incluyo el gráfico.